# org.apache.http.client.httpclient is abstract cannot be instantiated

Tags: java

Im trying to use apache HttpClient 4.1.2 but the debugger shows

```
org.apache.http.client.httpclient is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

when I do:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Any idea on how to use it then ?

Thx

Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the concrete implementations.

Answer (score 5):

You have to find an actual implementation for that class. Abstract classes can never be directly initiated.

The [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) knows 3 implementing classes you can use `DefaultHttpClient` and `ContentEncodingHttpClient`.

The javadoc even has a short sample on that topic.